# Python: Writing and updating a .json file from Dictionary

Tags: python, json

I am generating a dictionary and I want to write it in a .json file. Lets say I have the following code:

```
data = []
sample = {'Value 1': 16,  'Value 2': 1, 'Value 3': 2}
sample2 = {'Value 1': 10,  'Value 2': 1, 'Value 3': 2,'Value 4':[1,4]}
data.append(sample)
data.append(sample2)
```

I want to write `data` to a json format file to different lines. Something like this:

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
with open('trial.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp)
```

But this writes a file all in one line. How do I write it in order to be in different lines?

Furthermore, assuming that I have the file above in different lines: how can I update it? For example I want to insert a new row:

```
sample3 = {'Value 1': 1,  'Value 2': 8, 'Value 3': 4}
```

What code should I write to insert this to the same file without erasing the previous data? So to be like this:

[image]

Using the previous code block erasies the previous data.

**Edit:** A way to 'update' the file(not the most elegant) is the following:

```
with open('trial.json', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp)


sample3 = {'Value 1': 1,  'Value 2': 8, 'Value 3': 4}

with open('trial.json', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as feedsjson:
    feeds = json.load(feedsjson)

with open('trial.json','w',encoding='utf-8') as feedsjson:
    feeds.append(sample3)
    json.dump(feeds,feedsjson)
```

It can be seen that I am not using the `indent` option. An error pop-ups if I use it.

Comment: *"What code should I write to insert this to the same file without erasing the previous data?* - you can't really insert data into an existing file, the easiest way is to read its current content, edit it in memory then write out the whole new content.

Comment: shouldn't be a tricky way by using with `open("trial.json", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("dict in string format")` ? I am justing wondering, dont know.

Comment: Does it have to follow that format exactly? json.dump() allows for pretty printing with indents. e.g. json.dump(data, fp, indent=4)

Comment: But you don't want to append right at the end of the file, you want to replace at least the closing `]`.

Comment: JSON is not a database format. It is not intended to update a file on-the-fly. You have to read it the file to memory, update the memory object, and then print it back to the JSON file.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Its clear for the 'updating' issue now. I will use Mike's  suggestion for writing to json. Can I ask what is the difference between using `indent=4` or `indent=6` or any other number? Cause visually I dont see any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
with open('trial.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp, indent=2)
```

It will ask the `json.dump` to prettify your json encoded text.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json 
#SAMPLE_FILE.JSON
{'Value 1': 16,  'Value 2': 1, 'Value 3': 2}
a_file = open("sample_file.json", "r")
json_object = json.load(a_file)
a_file.close()
print(json_object)
OUTPUT
{'a': {'b': 1, 'c': 2}, 'd': 3}

json_object["Value 4"] = [1,4]

a_file = open("sample_file.json", "w")
json.dump(json_object, a_file)
a_file.close()
#SAMPLE_FILE.JSON
{'Value 1': 10,  'Value 2': 1, 'Value 3': 2,'Value 4':[1,4]}
```

More details [here](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-update-a-json-file-in-python)